# this.setState() is not a function -> when trying to save response on state

Tags: jquery, api, reactjs, get, undefined

I'm trying to save the response of a get request onto a property on state. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import './App.css';
import Card from './Card.js';
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar.js"
import star from './images/star.svg';
import wars from './images/wars.svg';
import $ from './../node_modules/jquery';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    gets: []      //THIS IS WHERE THE RESPONSE ARR SHOULD BE SAVED 
  }
}

////////////////////////////
//     GET REQUEST        //
////////////////////////////

getTheApi(){
$.get('http://localhost:3008/people', function(cool){
    console.log(cool) //<-- the response is correct (array of objs)
    this.setState({gets:cool}).bind(this)   //have tried w/ w/out .bind(this)
  })
}

render() {

console.log(this.state.gets); //shows as undefined

    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={star} alt="star-logo" />
          <span className='interview-text'>The Interview</span>
          <img src={wars} alt="wars-logo" />
          <span>WHATTTTTT</span>
        </div>
        <SearchBar />
        <Card />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I've tried multiple ways to get this to work, but no dice. I've tried `this.setState({gets:cool})` with and without bind. I've console logged the variable `cool` before `this.setState` and I am getting the correct array of objects. But when I then try to save my response to state it says

```
Type Error: this.setState() is not a function.
```

I've also tried invoking `getTheAPI()` inside of render, thinking state wasn't being updated because the function was never being run, but the errors persisted.

I just can't figure out why the response is defined in the function, but not out of the function, and why it's saying `this.setState()` is not a function.

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: Could be the scope of the this, in your code belongs to jquery not to react

Comment: Don't mix jQuery with React. There's zero need for jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this.

```
getTheApi(){
  let _this = this;
  $.get('http://localhost:3008/people', function(cool){
     console.log(cool) 
    _this.setState({gets:cool});
  })
}
```

And in your constructor

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    gets: []      //THIS IS WHERE THE RESPONSE ARR SHOULD BE SAVED 
  }
  this.getTheApi = this.getTheApi.bind(this);
}
```

Since the scope of `this` is not available in `callback` for `AJAX` request. You need to save it in another variable.

Answer (score 4):

The this inside the success callback function does not refer to the this of the Component. Since you are using ES6, you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which provide lexical scoping.

Example:

```
 getTheApi = () => {
     $.get('http://localhost:3008/people', (cool) => {
        this.setState({gets:cool})
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

**First**: bind the `getTheApi()` function so that it can access the state

**Second**:  bind the ajax success function and not the state

```
getTheApi = () =>{
$.get('http://localhost:3008/people', function(cool){
    console.log(cool) 
    this.setState({gets:cool})  
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: Class properties such as this are experimental